# Bootstrap Dropdown with tab pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a dropdown successfully with the tab content change. But the problem is, after I select the value in the dropdown to change the tab content - Let's say from `wan_static_ip` to `wan_dynamic_ip`, I cannot switch back to `wan_static_ip` again.

Another problem is, when the value has been selected it will become permanently selected and cannot be clicked again

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="borders col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#wan_static_ip" data-toggle="tab">Static IP</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#wan_dynamic_ip" data-toggle="tab">Dynamic IP</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#wan_pppoe" data-toggle="tab">PPPoE</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="wan_static_ip">1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="wan_dynamic_ip">2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="wan_pppoe">3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I m using the latest bootstrap v3.3.2

Answer (score 2):

A sample code of a tab dropdown button from getbootstrap.com

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
        <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
              Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Providing code is good but add some explanation to your post so, that it willbe helpful for other users

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution.
The reason for the problem is that the bootstrap selector inside the dropdown does not work well.
To solve this problem, you have to change and use this jQuery code according to the name of the classes of your choice.

```js
jQuery(".dropdown-item").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(this).attr("aria-selected", "true");
  jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  jQuery(".dropdown-item").not(this).attr("aria-selected", "false");
  jQuery(".dropdown-item").not(this).removeClass("active");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" id="standort" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" role="presentation">
      <a id="dropName" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Select</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="nav-item drop-item">
          <button class="dropdown-item nav-link active" id="tab-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabs-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-selected="true">
          Item 1
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item drop-item">
          <button class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="tab-2" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabs-2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-selected="false">
          Item 2
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="content">
    <div class="row tab-pane fade show active" id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-1">
      <H1>This Is Content Of Item 1 </H1>
    </div>
    <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-2">
      <H1>This Is Content Of Item 2 </H1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you have multiple tabs, how do to highlight the tab with the selected item too?